NodeJs- How to fix socket hangup error when running application using docker
I am getting the below error when using request module in NodeJs.
Error: socket hang up
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:524:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'

I am running my application using docker conatiner and the code is given below.
const reqUrl = 'http://localhost:90/';
for(let i=0; i< length;i++) {
  let newPayload = {
    servicePath: payload['servicePath'],
    payloadnumber: i+1,
    schema_file_name: payload['schema_file_name']
  }
  let result = await uBotHandler(newPayload);
}
uBotHandler = async (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({
      'url': reqUrl + payload['servicePath'],
      'method': 'POST',
      'json': true,
      'body': payload
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      console.log('error===> ', error);
      if (error) {
        responseObj = {
          status: 'error',
          msg: `Error occurred while performing rest api call. ${error}`,
          body: null
        }
        reject(responseObj);
      } else {
        responseObj = {
          status: 'success',
          msg: `Successfully performing rest api call.`,
          body: body
        };
        resolve(responseObj);
      }
    })
  });
}

Here I am sending multiple request in a loop. In first iteration of the loop the response is coming properly but in next iteration the request module is not sending any request instead its throwing the socket hangup error. I have tried same running the application without docker and its working as expected but with the docker container its throwing such error.
Can any expert help me to resolve this issue ?

If you're sending a request to http://localhost:90, you're trying to send it to the dnsix service in the current container.  If that what you mean, or does the URL need to point somewhere else?
